# A tool to save (in real time) the entries shown in Firefox's Network Monitor

Tags: networking, firefox, display, palemoon

It would be the best to describe the problem and hopefully someone will offer a solution.

- A firefox browser (pale moon actually)
- Automated work inside an HTTPS website
- Its Network Monitor is kept open, filtering used
- In the end, the NetMon shows a bunch of POST request entries and I need to perform as many 'Copy as cURL'.

The problem lies in the fact that the browser sometimes crashes/hangs (it happens even at idle times) and I can't afford that because I really need those POST requests.
Besides "find the cause of the crash/hang", would you kindly suggest a tool (software / addon) that will somehow have/export a copy of all the entries shown in the Network Monitor in such a real-time way that, in case the browser stops working, I will still have the POST entries I mentioned. Resuming the job won't be an issue but the lost POST requests will be a time completely wasted.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are using Developer Tools (F12) and looking at the Net tab.

You might consider copying everything on that tab into a text file.
This is done by:

- Click on some empty space inside the tab
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text.

The format of the copied text is voluminous (but still understandable)
and containing the POST commands.

Comment: Hello... before starting ? There would be 0 of the POST requests there if I copy Before I start the automated selenium-ide task. The POST requests will start appearing in the NetMon only if the automated task is started first. And the point of the automated task is not to monitor it myself, but to let it do the job by itself, and then me 'grabbing' the POST requests. If the browser crashes/hangs at mid-work, the POST requests which were done before that moment will be gone. Kindly let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Before starting to curl, while it's displayed. For automatic, you could use a web debugging proxy to list all POSTs, such as Telerik Fiddler.

Comment: I was aware about Fiddler but I was somewhat sure the HTTPS traffic is not something I could process properly with Fiddler. And I was sure it was alike Wireshark which I use for different purposes. Thank you for your suggestion I will check it out soon.